# Swift pow function returns -nan

Tags: ios, swift

I do have to two double variables, and want to calculate power of first one depends on second one.

In my case, when the first number is negative, the result is -nan.

Why this calculation causing this result and how to find a correct(rounded) answer.

```
    let x: Double = (1/3)
    let result: Double = pow(-0.0055649111736569, x)
    
    print("result is", result)
```

> result is -nan

```
let x: Double = (1/3)
let result: Double = pow(0.0055649111736569, x)

print("result is", result)
```

> result is 0.17720912405287548

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect Swift's `pow` follows all the [same rules as the one in C](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/pow.3.html), which include:

> A domain error occurs if x is finite and negative and y is finite and not
> an integer.

(This is straight out of  the [C spec](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf).)

The way you fix this is to check if the base is negative, and if so, make it positive, take the cube root, and then reapply the negative.

```
func cubeRoot(_ x: Double) -> Double {
    if x >= 0 {
        return pow(x, 1/3)
    } else {
        return -pow(-x, 1/3)
    }
}
```

One reason for this restriction is that the above is not correct. It's what you want, but it's wrong for several reasons. First, there's the whole ["what does this even mean?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/317546) question from mathematics. More practically, however, this does not work in the general case, and in fact does not work in any actual case.

In the general case, you're not taking the cube root; you're taking some arbitrary root, and the result will include complex values, which are not handled in this type.

But you're not even asking for the cube root here. You're asking for the `Double(1/3)` power. **That's not the same thing as 1/3.** 1/3 is a repeating value in binary, just like in decimal. `Double(1/3)` is just an approximation. So if you computed it correctly, you would have some residual imaginary component. You don't mean all that, even though it's what you've asked for. You *mean* the above `cubeRoot` function, so that's what you should write.

This problem applies to any odd root, because they're all are non-terminating in binary. So any place that it *could* work, it actually won't.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it was made to work this way?